# Issues selecting the first visible element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 3 tabs, Each tab has its own heading and content.

But I don't want to show all the 3 tabs, unless the user select to display a tab by checking the related checkbox, There are 3 related checkboxes, One for each tab.

Here is the code:

```js
//Function to hide all siblings but leave the clicked one
function hideAllChildrenButOne(parentId, toRevealId) {
 $('#' + parentId).children().css('display', 'none');
 $('#' + toRevealId).css('display', 'block');
}

//Function to show the tab header and content when a checkbox is checked
function showSection(parentId, toRevealId, self) {
 var relatedSection = $('#' + toRevealId).attr('data-section');

 
 if(self.is(':checked')){
  $('#' + toRevealId).addClass('inline-block');
  $('#' + toRevealId).addClass('tab_active');
  $('#' + toRevealId).siblings().removeClass('tab_active');
  $('#' + relatedSection).siblings().removeClass('active');
  $('#' + relatedSection).addClass('block');
  $('#' + relatedSection).addClass('active');
 }

 if ($('#'+self.attr('data-header')).hasClass('tab_active')){
                        var count = $(".tab-header:visible").length;        
   if(self.is(':checked') == false && count > 0){
       $(".tab-header:visible:first").addClass('tab_active');
       $('#'+$(".tab-header:visible:first").attr('data-section')).addClass('active');
     }
 }
 
 if(self.is(':checked') == false){
  $('#' + toRevealId).removeClass('inline-block');
  $('#' + toRevealId).removeClass('tab_active');
  $('#' + relatedSection).removeClass('block');
  $('#' + relatedSection).removeClass('active');
 }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 //On clicking a tab header('Father', 'Mother', 'Brother')
 $('.tab-header').click(function(event) {
  $(this).addClass('tab_active').siblings().removeClass('tab_active');
     var related_section = $(this).attr('data-section');
     hideAllChildrenButOne('relative_content', related_section);
 });


 //On changing any checkbox with name=relative[]
 $("input[name='relative[]']").change(function() {
     var self = $(this);
     showSection('relative_tabs', self.attr('data-header'), self);
 });

});
```

```css
.relative_container{
    position: relative;
    padding: 45px 15px 15px;
    margin: 0 -15px 15px;
    border-color: #e5e5e5 #eee #eee;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
 .relative_container {
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     background-color: #fff;
     border-color: #ddd;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     box-shadow: none;
 }
}
.relative_tabs{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 7px 0;
}
.relative_tabs:before{
 display: table;
 content: " ";
} 
.tab-header{
 display: none;
 margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.tab-header>a{
 margin-right: 2px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-header.tab_active>a{
 color: #555;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.relative_content div{
 display: none;
}
.relative_content>div.active{
 display: block;
}
.tab-content{
 display: none;
}
.hidden{
 display: none;
}
.inline-block{
 display: inline-block;
}
.block{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <label>Father<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Father" data-header="father-tab"></label>
 <label>Mother<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Mother" data-header="mother-tab"></label>
 <label>Guardian<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Guardian" data-header="guardian-tab"></label>
 
 <div class="relative_container">
  <div class="relative_header">
   <ul class="relative_tabs" id="relative_tabs">
    <li id="father-tab" data-section="Father_info" class="tab-header">
     <a>Father</a>
    </li> 
    <li data-section="Mother_info" class="tab-header" id="mother-tab">
     <a>Mother</a>
    </li>
    <li data-section="Guardian_info" class="tab-header" id="guardian-tab">
     <a>Guardian</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="relative_content" id="relative_content">
   <div class="tab-content" id="Father_info">Father Info</div>
   <div class="tab-content" id="Mother_info">Mother Info</div>
   <div class="tab-content" id="Guardian_info">Guardian Info</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Here is a fiddle for testing/editing:
https://jsfiddle.net/s83evtrm

Everything works fine except the following scenarios:

1- When I check all the 3 checkboxes starting from father checkbox, Then uncheck guardian tha father tab becomes active, When I uncheck father mother tab should become active, But this is not happening, I printed the first visible element in this case and it returned father instead of mother.

i think this could be resolved by moving the 3rd if condition:

```
if(self.is(':checked') == false){
    $('#' + toRevealId).removeClass('inline-block');
    $('#' + toRevealId).removeClass('tab_active');
    $('#' + relatedSection).removeClass('block');
    $('#' + relatedSection).removeClass('active');
}
```

Before the 2nd one:

```
if ($('#'+self.attr('data-header')).hasClass('tab_active')){
    var count = $(".tab-header:visible").length;
     if(self.is(':checked') == false && count > 0){
        $(".tab-header:visible:first").addClass('tab_active');
        $('#'+$(".tab-header:visible:first").attr('data-section')).addClass('active');
    }
}
```

But in this case the 2rd condition that becomes 3rd won't work.

2- When I check any other checkbox but not the father, Then check the other one, Then check father, Then uncheck father, None of the 2 other tabs become active.

PS: to make a tab active, `tab_active` class is added to the tab heading ('Father', 'Mother', ..etc) and `active` is added to the content ('Father Info', 'Mother Info', ..etc)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can try is to force a click on the first selected input if none of the tabs are active:

```js
// Function to hide all siblings but leave the clicked one
function hideAllChildrenButOne(parentId, toRevealId) {
  $('#' + parentId).children().css('display', 'none');
  $('#' + toRevealId).css('display', 'block');
}

// Function to show the tab header and content when a checkbox is checked
function showSection(parentId, toRevealId, self) {
  var relatedSection = $('#' + toRevealId).attr('data-section');

  if (self.is(':checked')) {
    $('#' + toRevealId).addClass('inline-block');
    $('#' + toRevealId).addClass('tab_active');
    $('#' + toRevealId).siblings().removeClass('tab_active');
    $('#' + relatedSection).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('#' + relatedSection).addClass('block');
    $('#' + relatedSection).addClass('active');
  }

  if ($('#'+self.attr('data-header')).hasClass('tab_active')) {
    var count = $('.tab-header:visible').length;
    if (self.is(':checked') == false && count > 0) {
      $('.tab-header:visible:first').addClass('tab_active');
      $('#' + $('.tab-header:visible:first').attr('data-section')).addClass('active');
    }
  }

  if (self.is(':checked') == false) {
    $('#' + toRevealId).removeClass('inline-block');
    $('#' + toRevealId).removeClass('tab_active');
    $('#' + relatedSection).removeClass('block');
    $('#' + relatedSection).removeClass('active');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // On clicking a tab header('Father', 'Mother', 'Brother')
  $('.tab-header').click(function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('tab_active').siblings().removeClass('tab_active');
    var related_section = $(this).attr('data-section');
    hideAllChildrenButOne('relative_content', related_section);
  });

  // On changing any checkbox with name=relative[]
  $('input[name="relative[]"]').change(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    showSection('relative_tabs', self.attr('data-header'), self);
    // If none of the tabs are active, then activate the first one by unchecking and rechecking it.
    if (!$('.tab_active').length) {
      $('input:checked').first().click().click();
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.relative_container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 45px 15px 15px;
  margin: 0 -15px 15px;
  border-color: #e5e5e5 #eee #eee;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .relative_container {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

.relative_tabs {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 7px 0;
}

.relative_tabs:before {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.tab-header {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.tab-header > a {
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-header.tab_active > a {
  color: #555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.relative_content div {
  display: none;
}

.relative_content > div.active {
  display: block;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>Father<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Father" data-header="father-tab"></label>
  <label>Mother<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Mother" data-header="mother-tab"></label>
  <label>Guardian<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Guardian" data-header="guardian-tab"></label>

  <div class="relative_container">
    <div class="relative_header">
      <ul class="relative_tabs" id="relative_tabs">
        <li id="father-tab" data-section="Father_info" class="tab-header">
          <a>Father</a>
        </li>
        <li data-section="Mother_info" class="tab-header" id="mother-tab">
          <a>Mother</a>
        </li>
        <li data-section="Guardian_info" class="tab-header" id="guardian-tab">
          <a>Guardian</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="relative_content" id="relative_content">
      <div class="tab-content" id="Father_info">Father Info</div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="Mother_info">Mother Info</div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="Guardian_info">Guardian Info</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That's not what i meant, All the tabs are hidden until the user checks one of the checkboxes at least, What I meant is when there are more than one checked checkboxes and the user uncheck the active one, One of the checked checkboxes should be active

Comment: Yes @maxwell, that's the behavior in my snippet. If you check Mother, then Guardian then Father, Father will be active, then if you uncheck Father, Mother will become active.

Comment: So you just added the condition `if (!$('.tab_active').length) {
           $('input:checked').first().click().click();
     };`? Or there are other changes?

Comment: Correct, that's the only change I made :)